# How to populate listbox with a list of all open forms

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a form with a listbox, and I want to be able to populate it with all open forms of the same application. However, I want to be able to select an Item from the listbox, and be able to close the form associated with that item in the list box. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to the issue. The following code works:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim myForms As FormCollection = Application.OpenForms

  For Each frmName As Form In myForms
    ListBox1.Items.Add(frmName.Name.ToString)
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If Not ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    Dim myForm As Form = Application.OpenForms(ListBox1.Text)
    myForm.Close()
  End If
End Sub
```

Where the code under `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` can very easily be placed in a button.

Answer (score 1):

[`My.Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.openforms.aspx) is a collection of the open forms in your project. So something like:

```
For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
    Me.SomeListBox.Items.Add(f)
Next
```

Then to close the selected item, it’s

```
DirectCast(Me.SomeListBox.SelectedItem, Form).Close()
```

Comment: Just a suggestion @minitech; you can't add a form to a listbox :) you may want to change that to: Me.SomeListBox.Items.Add(f.name)

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: Then the close thing will break! I don’t know what the string representation of a form is in a `ListBox`, but it will show up somehow. :) `Add` takes an object. (I don’t have Visual Studio at the moment, though…)

Comment: I tested out this method, and the listbox shows up with blank items, but items are in there, and if you close on of the items, the whole program closes.

Comment: @TheRyan722 that is because you need to add the name of the form buddy; instead of just ....Add(f) change that to: (f.Name)

Comment: @TheRyan722: Change your project settings not to close when the initial form is closed. My Project > Application, I believe.

Comment: I found an answer, and have posted it.